# from past import print_statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

Is there some equivalent to `from __future__ import print_function` that forward-ports the `print` statement from python 2.x?

An answer involving some `ipython` magic that lets me print without need of surrounding parens during prototyping is also acceptable.

Comment: If it's just for the interactive shell, you do not need to `print` at all, do you? Just write an expression and you see the result.

Comment: You may be looking for Ruby

Comment: @tobias_k Yes, but often I like printing info from functions, or printing multiple consecutive statements from within a single cell.

Comment: Any downvoters care to suggest question improvements?

Comment: Why do you even want `print` as a statement? The `print()` function can do everything the statement can, and more.

Comment: @jazzpi Not a particularly good programming reason... I appreciate the print function's improvements, but I try to reduce # of unnecessary keystrokes for health reasons. Difference between adding the statement/function to an existing line is an extra `Shift-( Ctrl-e Shift-)=6` keystrokes for me. I'd grep-change it when I'm done with the program but it makes it easier while developing, especially since I end up deleting most print statements by the end anyways.

Comment: If it's just to reduce typing and strain on wrists, you could also look for a editor / interactive shell that automatically inserts `()` after function names.

Comment: @tobias_k Good point--Sublime does this pretty well, but I'm kind of married to the ipython notebook these days. Looks like IPython's got the flexibility for my needs though.

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestion for IPython

```
%autocall
print "Hi"
```

Define magic with autocall on

```
from IPython.core.magic import register_line_magic
@register_line_magic
def p(line):
    print(line)
p "Hi"
```

Define magic with autocall off

```
from IPython.core.magic import register_line_magic
@register_line_magic
def p(line):
    print(eval(line))
%p "Again"
```

You could create a .config/ipython/profile_default/startup/autoprint.py file for you line magic functions.

Answer (score 0):

Provisional answer (A solution that doesn't involve a leading `/` will be preferred.): IPython [automatically calls](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-1.1.0/interactive/reference.html#automatic-parentheses-and-quotes) an object if line begins with a `/`, even if it's indented:

```
def f():
    /print 'foo'

f()
```

prints `foo`.

*Edit:*

1. IPython also has an [`%autocall`](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.magics.auto.html#IPython.core.magics.auto.AutoMagics.autocall) magic function that, well, automatically calls functions, so after doing `%autocall 1`, typing `print 3` in a cell acts like `print` in python 2.x (though this unfortunately doesn't work in function definitions like `/` does.
2. Also, since it's a function and not a statement, you can simply do `p = print`, so later `/p 'foo'` calls give you almost `pdb`-like behavior (something I was going for but that wasn't explicitly stated in the question).